# ¿Como puedo guardar un input en un archivo externo?

Tags: python, python-3.x

¿Como puedo guardar los input de python en un archivo externo para luego volver a encontraros con otro comando?

Por ejemplo, a la hora de crear un contraseñas y usuarios para luego recuperarlos e iniciar sesión.

Gracias.

Comment: Abres un archivo de salida, grabas los inputs. En el otro comando, abres el archivo de entrada y lo lees.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Hay muchas soluciones a tu problema, algunas mas optimas y seguras que otras.

En mi caso voy a explicarte una forma sencilla y rápida, que no debe usarse en aplicaciones que vayan a estar expuestas, ya que cualquier persona podría ver las claves.

La forma mas simple es usar el manejo de archivos de python.

```py
#Sintaxis basica


# Para abrir un fichero:
f = open ('ruta.txt','permisos')
    # Permisos disponibles: r (Lectura), w (Escritura), 
    # a(Escritua al final del archivo), w+ (Lectura y escritura)
    # a+(Lectura y escritura al final del archivo)
    
    #Ejemplo: f = open('ruta.txt', w+)

# Escribir en un archivo: 
f.write('Que quieres escribir?')

# Leer todo el contenido de un archivo
contenido_archivo = f.read()

# Leer solo una linea del archivo
linea_del_archio = f.readline()

# Cerrar un archivo
f.close()
```

**¡Importante!** Recuerda cerrar siempre los archivos.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como guardar y recuperar un usuario y contraseña

```py
# abro el archivo
f = open ('archivo.txt', 'w+')

# escribo algunos usuarios
f.write('admin:contra1234')
f.write('\nrudahee:contrasenaexcesivamentelarga')

# muevo el puntero a la primera posicion (Para saber la posicion se usa f.tell())
f.seek(0)


# recorro y voy mostrando cada una de las lineas del archivo.
for linea in f:
    print('=====================')
    print('la linea es: ', linea)
    name, passwd = linea.split(':') 
    print('nombre: ', name)
    print('contraseña: ', passwd)


f.close()
```

Ademas para facilitarte la tarea te dejo un par de enlaces con mucha mas informacion:

[Tienes un maravilloso articulo de Programming Historian aqui](https://programminghistorian.org/es/lecciones/trabajar-con-archivos-de-texto)

[Mucha mas informacion gracias a la web: pythones.net](https://pythones.net/archivos-en-python-3/)

Espero todo te sea de mucha ayuda. Un saludo.