# buscar un dato del archivo de texto en python

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy haciendo un programa el cual consiste en **agregar, modificar, buscar y eliminar un usuario.**

Cuando hago un registro me lo guarda en un `.txt`, pero ahora que quiero **modificar buscar o eliminar un dato dentro de mi `.txt`**, lo que quiero hacer es buscar  en mi txt buscar a un usuario y me arroje todos los datos del usuario.

Esto es lo que llevo de momento en mi código, lo estoy haciendo de forma gráfica.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


def guardar_info():
  nombre_info = nombre.get()
  domicilio_info = domicilio.get()
  usuario_info = usuario.get()
  contrase_info = contraseña.get()
  rol_info = Combo.get()
  print(nombre_info,' ',domicilio_info,' ', usuario_info,' ', contrase_info,' ',rol_info)

  file = open("user.txt", "w")
  file.write(nombre_info)
  file.write(domicilio_info)
  file.write(usuario_info)
  file.write(contrase_info)
  file.write(rol_info)
  file.close()
  print(" El Usuario ", nombre_info, " se ah registrado")

  nombre_entry.delete(0, END)
  domicilio_entry.delete(0, END)
  usuario_entry.delete(0, END)
  contrase_entry.delete(0, END)
  Combo.delete(0, END)
   
screen = Tk()
screen.geometry("500x500")
screen.title("Registro de Usuarios")
heading = Label(text = "Formulario", bg = "#EF8C77", fg = "black", width = "500", height = "3")
heading.pack()

 
nombre_text = Label(text = "Nombre Completo * ",)
domicilio_text = Label(text = "Domicilio * ",)
usuario_text = Label(text = "Usuario * ",)
contrase_text = Label(text = "Contraseña * ",)
rol_text = Label(text = "Rol * ",)

nombre_text.place(x = 15, y = 70)
domicilio_text.place(x = 15, y = 140)
usuario_text.place(x = 15, y = 210)
contrase_text.place(x = 15, y = 280)
rol_text.place(x = 15, y = 350)

nombre = StringVar()
domicilio = StringVar()
usuario = StringVar()
contraseña = StringVar()
Combo = StringVar()

vlist = ["Usuario","Operador","Administrado"]
Combo.set("Selecciona Uno")
Combo = ttk.Combobox(values = vlist, width = "30")
Combo.place(x = 15, y = 350)

nombre_entry = Entry(textvariable = nombre, width = "30")
domicilio_entry = Entry(textvariable = domicilio, width = "30")
usuario_entry = Entry(textvariable = usuario, width = "30")
contrase_entry = Entry(textvariable = contraseña, width = "30")
nombre_entry.place(x = 15, y = 100)
domicilio_entry.place(x = 15, y = 180)
usuario_entry.place(x = 15, y = 240)
contrase_entry.place(x = 15, y = 310)

register = Button(screen,text = "Registrar", width = "30", height = "2", command = guardar_info, bg = "#EF8C77")
register.place(x = 15, y = 380)
```

Comment: Buenas. ¿podría servirte este articulo de aquí? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/como-puedo-guardar-un-input-en-un-archivo-externo/394628#394628

Comment: Y si en lugar de usar archivos .txt creas una base de datos y una tabla? Te seria más facil manejar los datos.