# Aplicacion con tkinter

Tags: python

tengo un problema y es que configurando ventanas con tkinter no logro hacer funcional la opcion de "Guardar", "Guardar Como" y "Abrir". Cuando creo los archivos, estos figuran como que se guardan pero cuando los busco para abrirlos no me aparecen. Adjunto código, es en Python y uso sublimeText3

root es la raiz de la interfaz

```
def onOpen():
    archivo = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "C:/", title = "open file", filetypes = 
(("Archivos de Texto", "*.txt"), ("Archivos PDF", "*.pdf" ), ("Todos los Archivos", "*.*"))) #Abrir
    print(archivo) #imprime la ruta del archivo en la consola

def onSave(): #Intente guardar el filedialog en una variable como arriba pero me surge error
    print(filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir = "C:/", title = "open file", filetypes = 
(("Archivos de Texto", "*.txt"), ("Archivos PDF", "*.pdf" ), ("Todos los Archivos", "*.*")))) #Guardar

barraMenu = Menu()
root.config(menu = barraMenu, width = 300, height = 300)

archivoMenu = Menu(barraMenu, tearoff = 0)
archivoMenu.add_command(label = "Abrir", command = onOpen)
archivoMenu.add_command(label = "Nuevo", command = Nuevo)
archivoMenu.add_command(label = "Guardar", command = onSave)

barraMenu.add_cascade(label = "Archivo",      menu = archivoMenu)
```

Comment: Que error te tira cuando ejecutas `onSave`?

Comment: cuando modifico la funcion por: 
 def onSave(): 
 archivo = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir = "C:/", title = "open file", filetypes = (("Archivos de Texto", "*.txt"), ("Archivos PDF", "*.pdf" ), ("Todos los Archivos", "*.*")))
        print(archivo) #Guardar

Comment: y el error que me tira es:    print(archivo) #Guardar
                           ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que el problema reside en que no estas utilizando correctamente el manejo de ficheros de Python. Y por lo que pones en los comentarios debes tener cuidado con la identacion de tu código, es muy importante.

Te dejo por aquí como sería un nuevo archivo, un abrir, y un guardar, para que así tengas un modelo de donde sacar el guardar como y otros que te pudieran hacer falta.

```py
// importamos los componentes necesarios.
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog as FileDialog
from io import open

ruta = "" # La utilizaremos para almacenar la ruta del fichero

def nuevo():
    # Un nuevo fichero borra todo lo escrito en un campo de texto, 
    # pero no hace nada con los archivos existentes en el disco duro
    global ruta
    mensaje.set("Nuevo fichero")
    ruta = ""
    texto.delete(1.0, "end")
    root.title("Mi editor")

def abrir():
    # Abrir nuevo fichero. 
    global ruta
    mensaje.set("Abrir fichero")
    ruta = FileDialog.askopenfilename(
        initialdir='.',  # Ruta inicial, la carpeta actual
        filetype=(("Ficheros de texto", "*.txt"),), # Tipos de archivo txt
        title="Abrir un fichero de texto")

    if ruta != "": 
        # Si se selecciona una ruta
        fichero = open(ruta, 'r')   # Abrela como un archivo en modo lectura
        contenido = fichero.read()  # Lee el contenido
        texto.delete(1.0,'end')     # Borra lo que haya escrito en el campo de texto donde se vaya a insertar el contenido del fichero
        texto.insert('insert', contenido)  # Inserta el contenido del fichero
        fichero.close() # Cierra el fichero
        root.title(ruta + " - Mi editor")  # Cambia el nombre de la ventana.


def guardar():
    # Guardar un texto
    mensaje.set("Guardar fichero")
    if ruta != "":
        # Si existe una ruta
        contenido = texto.get(1.0,'end-1c') # Obten todo el contenido del campo de texto 
        fichero = open(ruta, 'w+') # Abre el fichero con permisos de escritura
        fichero.write(contenido)  # Escribe el contenido
        fichero.close()  # Cierra el fichero
        mensaje.set("Fichero guardado correctamente")
    else:
        # Si no existe una ruta, se debe guardar como.
        guardar_como()


# metodos como guardar como, etc......

# Configuración de la raíz
root = Tk()
root.title("Mi editor")


# Menú superior
menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)

# Aqui vamos a agregar los comandos al menu.
filemenu.add_command(label="Nuevo", command=nuevo)
filemenu.add_command(label="Abrir", command=abrir)
filemenu.add_command(label="Guardar", command=guardar)

# Aqui sigue el codigo, pero no es importante...
```

Como ves, en este ejemplo, cuando tengo que escribir o leer un archivo es importante usar el manejo de fichero de Python, puedes obtener mas información en los siguientes enlaces de interes:

**Documentacion Oficial de Python**
https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

**Otra pregunta que trata la lectura y escritura de archivos**
[¿Como puedo guardar un input en un archivo externo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/como-puedo-guardar-un-input-en-un-archivo-externo/394628#394628)

Espero que sea de utilidad, un saludo.

Comment: muchas gracias me estaba faltando esto